# Can multiple full-screen Intent activities launched by alarm notifications co-exist (on top of each other)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an alarm/reminder app that uses `.setFullScreenIntent` in its notification builder. As a result, when the phone is locked/screen off and the notification triggers, the full screen activity shows up and can wake up the screen. It works well.

But here's the problem: say the user missed this full screen notification entirely, and never cleared it (by clicking the dismiss button I put on this screen). A while later, another notification comes in. It will override the previous one entirely.

Now if the user comes back, only the latest full screen notification is shown. After dismissing it (which calls `finishActivity` in the code), the previous ones are not shown beneath it, even though they are present in the notification area.

The activity is already in `standard` mode, not `singleTop`, so multiple instances should have been allowed. I also made sure to set different `requestCode` on all of the underlying intents.

Ideally, I want multiple such full-screen notifications to stack on top of another (last in, first out) so the user can clear them one by one without missing any of them.

Is it an Android limitation that only one instance of full-screen notification is allowed per app at a time?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also had `launchMode` set to `standard`. Took me several hours but got it to work by removing `setContentIntent()` in my notificationBuilder while retaining `setFullScreenIntent()`.